# Going to Android Task Switcher causes Native window to be destroyed

Tags: android-ndk, android-lifecycle, android-9.0-pie, android-task

If my [NDK based app](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/struct/a-native-activity) is running, and I swipe up from bottom, to get the Task Switcher, my Native Window is destroyed.

Is this normal behaviour? I see this on Android9, and I could have sworn that going to the task switcher in older Android OS versions would not destroy the window?

So bringing up the task switcher causes `onNativeWindowDestroyed()` being triggered, which leads to a **APP_CMD_TERM_WINDOW** to be posted and handled by my app by destroying all its OpenGL resources.

It seems wasteful to completely destroy everything, and rebuild everything, merely because the user brought up the task switcher, even if the same task is foregrounded again?

Is this according to spec? Can it be avoided?

My app uses [android_native_app_glue.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/4948c163663ecc343c97e4c2a2139234f1d3273f/ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.h) and properly implements the Android app life-cycle.

[image]

Comment: This is an implementation detail, might not reproduce on a different device with Android 9. You don't need to destroy all GL resources, whatever you can reuse on a new native window, can stay.

Comment: For me, same behavior happens on API 21 (Android 5.0.2).